# Find the directional derivative of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ at the point $(1,2)$ in the direction of the path $\textbf{r}(t)= (t^3,2t)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find the directional derivative of the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$ at the point $(1,2)$ in the direction of the path, $$\textbf{r}(t)=\textbf{i}t^3+\textbf{j}2t = (t^3,2t)$$ passing through this point. (Hint, the direction of the path $\textbf{r}(t)$ at each t is given by $\textbf{r'}(t)$).

Round your answer to the nearest three decimal places.

I've started to answer the equation by taking partial derivatives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{-x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= \frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,2)= \frac{3}{25}$$ and 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,2)= \frac{-4}{25}$$

Therefore the gradient is $$\nabla f(1,2) = \frac{3}{25}\textbf{i}+\frac{-4}{25}\textbf{j}$$

The directional derivative at $(1,2)$ in the direction of $\textbf{r}$ is

$D_rf(1,2) = \nabla f(1,2)⋅\textbf{r}$

$=\frac{3t^3}{25}+(\frac{-8t}{25})$

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

The point $(1,2)$ corresponds to $r(t_0)$ for which time $t_0$? Once you have that then the direction derivative is given by,

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \Bigr|_{t=t_0} f(r(t)) = \nabla f(r(t_0)) \cdot r'(t_0)$$

I think you just forgot the evaluations. The relationship I am using is that if $\gamma(t_0) = p$ and $\gamma'(t_0) = \vec{v}$ then the two are the same,

$$ D_{\vec{v}}f(p)=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t= 0} f(p+ t\vec{v}) = \frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t = t_0}f(\gamma(t))$$

This follows from the fact that the LHS gives $\nabla f(p) \cdot \vec{v}$ and the RHS gives $\nabla f(\gamma(t_0)) \cdot \gamma'(t_0)$ which are equivalent.